# How to create a patch for a whole directory to update it?

Tags: diff, patch

I know there are several threads on this already, but no one has fully explained exactly how to perform the initial diff to create the patch file, then how to *apply* that patch to the initial directory to update it.

In my case, there is a directory of files that anyone can download from the web. I have taken that directory and made changes to it, and want to create a patch file such that others can apply it to the downloaded directory to reproduce exactly what I have in my modified directory.

Help? What do I need to tell the other person with respect to how to apply my patch?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

I just had this same problem - lots of advice on how to half do it. Well, here is what I did to get both the patching and unpatching to work:

To Create the Patch File:

1. Put copies of both directories in say /tmp, so we can create the patch
   file, or if brave, get them side by side - in one directory.
2. Run an appropriate diff on the two directories, old and new:

   ```
   diff -ruN orig/ new/ > file.patch
   # -r == recursive, so do subdirectories
   # -u == unified style, if your system lacks it or if recipient
   #       may not have it, use "-c"
   # -N == treat absent files as empty
   ```

If a person has the orig/ directory, they can recreate the new one by running patch.

To Recreate the new folder from old folder and patch file:

1. Move the patch file to a directory where the orig/ folder exists
2. This folder will get clobbered, so keep a backup of it somewhere, or
   use a copy.

   ```
   patch -s -p0 < file.patch
   # -s == silent except errors
   # -p0 == needed to find the proper folder
   ```
3. At this point, the orig/ folder contains the new/ content, but still
   has its old name, so:

   ```
   mv orig/ new/    # if the folder names are different
   ```

Comment: I'm a mac guy so no idea. What you have to do is check the options for patch and diff on Cygwin. That's why I added the comments above on what the options mean - so if one or the other program offers different options you can figure out what to change to get it to work. Conceptually all patch/diff programs should support the functionality.

Comment: @CharanPai "diff" does not support binary files, so I assume not. You might be able to create your own command file wrapper to do this. What you would do is binhex your binary data files - create a text file for each in binhex or similar ascii format. Then diff those files, and after the patch is applied, unbinhex the (possibly revised) binhex file bad into binary.

Comment: no, -a would work for that. treats all files as text.

Comment: diff -ruN orig/ new/ > file.patch, creates patch with orig/ and new/ dir names in patch file. How do I get  "a/" and "b/" instead?

Comment: @VikramDattu I'm not sure I understand the question - "orig/" and "new/" are example names - you can use "a/" and "b/" if you want

Comment: @DavidH is it possible to omit those outer directory names? Or is it neccessary that patch should contain new and orig directory names?

Comment: @VikramDattu I really don't know - I did this 4 years ago on a one-time project.

Comment: `patch` was patching the `new/` not `orig/` directory for me, but I found the `-d` option which allows you to say `cd` into that directory first before applying the patch and then you can adjust the `-p N` argument accordingly.

Comment: Is it possible to apply the patch without requiring that directories named `orig` or `new` exist?

Comment: @Flimm no it is not.

Comment: @VikramDattu It is possible.

Comment: @VikramDattu well you should tell him how

Answer (score 13):

I needed to create a patch file and send it to someone so they could update their directory to match mine.  There are many caveats with [diff](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) and [patch](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/patch.1.html) however, so it ended up taking me hours to figure out something so conceptually simple.  Absolute paths seem to be preferred over relative paths, and many of the options seem to have evolved from niche use cases.  I finally figured out a solution based on [David H's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9982282/539149), with additional tips from [Lakshmanan Ganapathy](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/12/patch-command-examples)):

- Back up your `directory` to `directory.orig`
- Modify your `directory` to reach the desired state
- Save diff from `directory.orig` to `directory` in `file.patch` so name matches for recipient

Here are my notes:

```
# to create patch:
# copy <directory> backup to something like <directory>.orig alongside it
cp -r <path_to>/<directory> <path_to>/<directory>.orig
# create/update/delete files/folders in <directory> until desired state is reached
# change working directory to <directory>
cd <path_to>/<directory>
# create patch file alongside <directory>
diff -Naru ../<directory>.orig . > ../file.patch
# -N --new-file Treat absent files as empty.
# -a --text Treat all files as text.
# -r --recursive Recursively compare any subdirectories found.
# -u -U NUM --unified[=NUM] Output NUM (default 3) lines of unified context.

# to apply patch:
# change working directory to <directory>
cd <path_to>/<directory>
patch -s -p0 < <path_to>/file.patch
# -s or --silent or --quiet Work silently, unless an error occurs.
# -pN or --strip=N Strip smallest prefix containing num leading slashes from files.

# to undo patch (note that directories created by patch must be removed manually):
# change working directory to <directory>
cd <path_to>/<directory>
patch -Rs -p0 < <path_to>/file.patch
# -R or --reverse Assume that patch was created with the old and new files swapped.
# -s or --silent or --quiet Work silently, unless an error occurs.
# -pN or --strip=N Strip smallest prefix containing num leading slashes from files.
```

Comment: It’s `-p0` that overcomplicated things. You could just strip it off.

Answer (score 3):

Check out open source Scarab C++ library: https://github.com/loyso/Scarab

It does exactly what you described.
It builds per-file diff using xdelta library and puts it to archive package. You can redistribute that package and apply the difference. There are binaries for Win32.

I'm the author of Scarab project.

Answer (score 1):

## Heads-up

Do not use `-p0` unless you understand how `patch` works.

---

## Diff

Create a deep (recursive) `.diff` between two directories in the same parent directory. A `.diff` file is a file that describes all the textual differences.

```
diff --unified --recursive --no-dereference ORIGINAL/ PATCHED/ > patch.diff
```

- `--unified`: to format the output into a “*unified context diff*.”
- `--recursive`: to create a deep `.diff`.
- `--no-dereference`: not to follow symbolic links.

Although the directory names, `ORIGINAL` and `PATCHED`, are included in file paths in the output, `patch.diff`, they are not important (“won’t be used later on”).

## Patch

With the `patch.diff` file, you can patch *any* directory of the same hierarchical structure. **You don’t need the directories named `ORIGINAL` and `PATCHED` anymore.**

For example, this command patches the `directory_to_apply_the_patch_on/` directory according to the `patch.diff`.

```
patch --directory=directory_to_apply_the_patch_on/ --strip=1 < patch.diff
```

- `--directory`: to set the working directory for `patch`.

`patch` assumes that file paths in `patch.diff` are relative to the *working directory*. Those paths have preceding `PATCHED/`, so you need to strip it first unless you have a `PATCHED` directory to patch in your working directory.

`--strip=<N>` or `-p<N>` strips the first *N* segments (delimited by slashes) from the file paths specified in the `patch.diff` file. `--strip=1` strips the topmost directory `PATCHED/` from all the destination file paths, making them relative to `directory_to_apply_the_patch_on/` instead.

> [Vikram Dattu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3249583/vikram-dattu): is it possible to omit those outer directory names? Or is it neccessary that patch should contain `new` and `orig` directory names?

> [Flimm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247696/flimm): Is it possible to apply the patch without requiring that directories named `orig` or `new` exist?

Yes, and that’s what `--strip=1` is for.

For me, I prefer this:

```
patch --directory=directory_to_apply_the_patch_on/ --unified --strip=1 --posix --force --set-utc --verbose < patch.diff
```

- `--unified`: to interpret the `.diff` file as a unified context diff, skipping format guessing.
- `--posix`: to behave the POSIX-compliant way.
- `--force`: not to ask questions on failure.
- `--set-utc`: to update the *modified times* of patched files.
- `--verbose`: to print what it’s thinking while trying to patch.

Comment: Interested to know what OS you use, as none of the diff options you use here are supported on macOS

Comment: @DavidH I use Debian 12 and `diff` (GNU `diffutils`) 3.8. The options `--unified[=NUM]` and `--recursive` are also known as `-u`, `-U NUM` and `-r`. Mac has been supporting them since macOS was [Mac OS X](https://ss64.com/osx/diff.html).