# Bitnami WordPress site re-setup

Tags: wordpress, migration, localhost, bitnami

so I have successfully installed Bitnami on my Linux. Purchased a theme from themeforest created a couple of pages using visual composer and some other plugins, customized some theme options, created a child theme and added some custom css in it. All well and dandy.

Now I'm trying to transfer the whole thing on other computer with some demands if possible. For better understanding of what I'm after lets simplify some things. Lets call:

The original(no changes have been made) purchased theme zip ...... T1

Same but customized theme on my first computer ...... T2

Child theme on my first computer ...... C1

What I'm trying to do on second computer:

1. Installing a T1
2. Installing a C1
3. Importing all the changed files between T2 and T1

So far I've done steps 1 and 2 successfully but before proceeding with step 3 I need some help. Is it smart to use some program that compares two directories and finds the files that don't match or is there a better way of doing what I want? I would like to do the step 1 because every time when the theme is updated I can simply import a new T1 and then repeat the step 3. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here,

You can use commands `diff` and `patch` in Linux to see differences between two folders and then apply those differences to the second folder. You can find a step-by-step guide in the thread below.

[How to create a patch for a whole directory to update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980186/how-to-create-a-patch-for-a-whole-directory-to-update-it)

Hope it helps,

Gonzalo