# How to make use of .diff file in Windows

Tags: diff

I have a .diff file containing a ton of changes across a ton of files.

I have earlier applied diffs manually using WinMerge. But this diff has way too many files and changes.

Is there any tool in windows for implementing the changes listed in a .diff file?
I find the following seemingly relevant thread cryptic and beyond my comprehension abilities:
[How to apply a .diff file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274840/how-to-apply-a-diff-file)

Comment: diff is to patch as apples are to cinnamon...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I apply a diff patch on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517257/how-do-i-apply-a-diff-patch-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, what you need can be in TortoiseMerge. http://tortoisesvn.net/TortoiseMerge.html Please have a look at the Applying patches part here.

Answer (score 0):

Refer: [How to create a patch for a whole directory to update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980186/how-to-create-a-patch-for-a-whole-directory-to-update-it)

```
diff -u orig_file_path new_file_path > file.patch
```